# predicting the next event with a list of dates

Tags: probability

I have a list of events. Now I'm looking for a way to predict the next events. Unfortunately I can't see a pattern. What possibilities do I have and how do I use them?

```
16.07.2019
13.07.2019
11.07.2019
07.07.2019
30.06.2019
28.06.2019
05.06.2019
01.06.2019
20.05.2019
15.05.2019
06.05.2019
04.05.2019
07.04.2019
08.02.2019
31.01.2019
18.01.2019
14.01.2019
12.01.2019
07.01.2019
02.01.2019
28.12.2018
19.12.2018
16.12.2018
09.12.2018
06.12.2018
03.12.2018
01.12.2018
28.11.2018
24.11.2018
22.11.2018
18.11.2018
06.11.2018
03.11.2018
27.10.2018
22.10.2018
18.10.2018
13.10.2018
25.09.2018
16.09.2018
13.09.2018
11.09.2018
09.09.2018
13.08.2018
08.08.2018
05.08.2018
01.08.2018
27.07.2018
24.07.2018
12.07.2018
10.07.2018
01.06.2018
30.05.2018
27.05.2018
25.05.2018
22.05.2018
20.05.2018
19.04.2018
17.01.2018
23.11.2017
31.07.2017
24.07.2017
21.07.2017
18.07.2017
14.07.2017
04.07.2017
01.07.2017
27.06.2017
25.06.2017
```

Update: add weekday overview
[weekday overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M5SW.png)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a math puzzle (the dates follow some exact pattern), or a statistics exercise (the dates follow some pattern, but with minor random deviations)?

Comment: It's a recurring event in the real world. I don't know the influences on the event and when it will occur next, but I want to start or end my vacation with the highest possible probability at this event.

Comment: Then it might help if we knew what kind of event it was. Is it geological? Is it a concert?

Comment: A plane that I would love to fly once.

Comment: Extrapolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation) is as much an art as a science, but the Wikipedia essay should give you some idea of the possibilities and their limitations.

Comment: Have you had a look at that link, Frank?

Comment: Not yet. But I will